# Apache rewrite rules inside a virtual host

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm having some trouble with migrating my rewrite rules from `.htaccess` to a `VirtualHost`.

When I'm using below Directory outside the `VirtualHost` it works, but I get some authentication errors - so I'm wondering to what I should change it to make it work inside the `VirtualHost`.

Or should they be added to `<Directory /var/www/server/>`

Rules:

```
<Directory /var/www/server/subfolder/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@server.com
Servername server.com
ServerAlias server2 server2.com server server.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/server

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/server/>
    AuthType NTLM
    AuthName Server
    require valid-user

    PythonAuthenHandler pyntlm
    PythonOption Domain SERVER.COM
    PythonOption PDC xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    PythonOption BDC xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/server.com_error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/server.com_access.log combined env=!nolog
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just leave out the <directory>, and place it directly inside the virtualhost

Comment: @Gerben - I added
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^/subfolder/$1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]`
inside the `VirtualHost` - but now it doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: @Gerben - I only get 404's now, so the rules aren't triggering like they were when I had them in the `<Directory>` outside the `<VirtualHost>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the authentication issue for me was to add

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to the existing `<Directory /var/www/server/subfolder/>`.

Though I still only managed to get it to work when having `<Directory>` outside of `<VirtualHost>`.

Thanks all.